# Bigquery schedule query creating resulting in error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a scheduled job based out of saved query in big query. I'm following steps as per documentation  [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query)

After entering all the filelds, I'm getting response "**Error creating scheduled query: Aq**" with no additional details.

In on BigQuery documentation also, I didn't find anything.

I could run the query which I'm trying to create a schedule for, is running fine and giving appropriate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that, when schedule query is created for first time, the console is taking permission by take user to new tab in browser. Browser settings was suppressing it.

After acknowledging the required permissions, I could create scheduled query successfully.